# Is an holomorphic function injective if $\| f'(z)\| > 0 $?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there any holomorphic function $f$ which isn't injective, even if $ \forall z $ $\| f'(z)\| > 0$  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for example $f(z) = e^z $

Answer (score 1):

$\exp$ isn't injective, it is even periodic.